# Loop through a table to find specific id's

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a table that I'm trying to insert a paypal button in the last cell of the table which is blank. I'm not sure how many rows will be in the table and I have the id's hard coded now which works. The id's begin with el and a number for each row then _qryMyReservedSlots_Payment

```
['#el1_qryMyReservedSlots_Payment', '#el2_qryMyReservedSlots_Payment', '#el3_qryMyReservedSlots_Payment'].forEach(function(selector) {
        paypal.Button.render({ 
        ...paypal code...
        });
});
```

to be more efficient, how can I loop through the id's so I don't have to hard code them?
Scott

Comment: Please share the markup

Comment: Try document.querySelectorAll('[id^=el]').forEach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure how many rows will be in the table and I have the id's
>   hard coded now which works

Use `querySelectorAll` and **attribute contains selector - `*`**

```
var allRows = document.querySelectorAll( "tr[id*='qryMyReservedSlots_Payment']");
Array.from( allRows ).forEach( function(rowElement){
  //logic with rowElement
})
```

Comment: Thank you. A slight modification worked  
    document.querySelectorAll( "span[id*='qryMyReservedSlots_Payment']").forEach(function(selector) {

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for (var el = 1; el < 4; el++) {
    var selector = `#el${el}_qryMyReservedSlots_Payment`
    ...
}
```

or more old-fashioned:

```
for (var el = 1; el < 4; el++) {
    var selector = '#el' + el + '_qryMyReservedSlots_Payment'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need them to have unique ids ?  You should give them a class and then do something like `document.getElementsByClassName(className).forEach(...)`.

If you insist on having unique ids (which, again, is not needed and this is exactly one of the reasons why we have classes), your could would be something like this:

```
while (document.getElementById(`el${ counter++ }_qryMyReservedSlots_Payment`)) {
  paypal.Button.render({ 
    ...paypal code...
  });
}
```

Again, this is not good because each time you query the id, you are hitting the DOM.  You should really get it all at once, manipulate in-memory, and then commit all your changes in as few DOM calls as possible.